# How can I skip the media-query in a Stylus function?

Tags: css, media-queries, stylus

I have a function in Stylus like this:

```
fn($margin, $padding)
  width 100%
  margin $margin
  padding $padding
  @media (min-width: 500px)
    width 50%
    float left
```

It works well until I want to use a second media query changing the values of the function:

```
div
  fn(3px, 5px)
  @media (min-width: 700px)
    fn(6px, 25px)
```

I get this css:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  div {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  div {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 6px;
    padding: 25px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) and (min-width: 500px) {
  div {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Obviously this is not what I want because the media query of the function overwrites some properties of the new media query.

Would there be any way to skip that part of the function when I call the function from a media query?

**EDIT (expand the explanation):**

For example a user writes: `grid (3, 10px)` and a grid of three columns is generated with 10px gutter. That grid is responsive, with less than 500px there is only one column. At the same time the user might want to make their own breakpoints, for example:

```
div
   grid(3, 10px)
   @media (min-width: 700px)
     grid(4, 20px)
```

What I want is to keep the media query 500px by default without the user having to define it, so I have put it in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It doesn't work with block mixins that I use for media-queries but with media-queries in normal syntax works fine. Just have to use the `current-media()` function, if empty continue, if not skip de block. That easy :).

Stylus code:

```
fn($margin, $padding)
  width 100%
  margin $margin
  padding $padding
  if current-media() is ''
    @media (min-width: 500px)
      width 50%
      float left

div
  fn(3px, 5px)
  @media (min-width: 700px)
    fn(6px, 25px)
```

CSS output:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  div {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  div {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 6px;
    padding: 25px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use it like this:

```
fn($width, $margin, $padding)
  width $width
  margin $margin
  padding $padding
  float: left

@media (min-width: 500px)
  div 
    fn(50%, 3px, 5px)

@media (min-width: 700px)
  div 
    fn(100%, 6px, 25px)
```

Which will result in the following css:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  div {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 6px;
    padding: 25px;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

And even clearer way would be to define the common attributes at first and then use the media queries like this:

```
fn($width, $margin, $padding)
  width $width
  margin $margin
  padding $padding

div 
  float: left

@media (min-width: 500px)
  div 
    fn(50%, 3px, 5px)

@media (min-width: 700px)
  div 
    fn(100%, 6px, 25px)
```

**EDIT based on your comment:**

In the case you mentioned you could use a mixin like this:

```
media_queries = {
  small  : "(min-width: 500px)",
  medium  : "(min-width: 700px)"
}

for_breakpoint(breakpoints)
  conditions = ()
  for breakpoint in breakpoints
    push(conditions, media_queries[breakpoint])
  conditions = join(", ", conditions)
  @media conditions
    {block}

fn($width, $margin, $padding)
  width $width
  margin $margin
  padding $padding

div
  float left
  +for_breakpoint(small)
    fn(50%, 3px, 5px)
  +for_breakpoint(medium)
    fn(100%, 6px, 25px)
```

The outcome of this would be:

```
div {
  float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  div {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 6px;
    padding: 25px;
  }
}
```

You can obviously add as many breakpoints as you want and you cant even include more statements like for example `small  : "only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 700px)",` in your breakpoints.

See it in action: [Stylus online editor](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=media_queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20small%20%20%3A%20%22(min-width%3A%20500px)%22%2C%0A%20%20medium%20%20%3A%20%22(min-width%3A%20700px)%22%0A%7D%0A%0Afor_breakpoint(breakpoints)%0A%20%20conditions%20%3D%20()%0A%20%20for%20breakpoint%20in%20breakpoints%0A%20%20%20%20push(conditions%2C%20media_queries%5Bbreakpoint%5D)%0A%20%20conditions%20%3D%20join(%22%2C%20%22%2C%20conditions)%0A%20%20%40media%20conditions%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bblock%7D%0A%0Afn(%24width%2C%20%24margin%2C%20%24padding)%0A%20%20width%20%24width%0A%20%20margin%20%24margin%0A%20%20padding%20%24padding%0A%0Adiv%0A%20%20float%20left%0A%20%20%2Bfor_breakpoint(small)%0A%20%20%20%20fn(50%25%2C%203px%2C%205px)%0A%20%20%2Bfor_breakpoint(medium)%0A%20%20%20%20fn(100%25%2C%206px%2C%2025px))

Comment: Thank you but that solution does not help me completely. The function I have is more complex than the example I used, it belongs to a grid system that I'm doing. The media-querie must be in the function and take the values passed to it without having to write it twice.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer according to your comment. Hopefully the edit is helpful to you.

Comment: That's not what I want, my English is not very good and maybe I have not explained well. Already I have a mixin for breakpoints. I edit the question to try to explain it better.

Comment: Can you add what you want the outcome of your css to be please?

Comment: I don't want the last rule: `@media (min-width: 700px) and (min-width: 500px)`

Comment: In my latest example it does not do such thing. Let me edit the answer and put the outcome of the css there and let me know what is wrong with it if there is something wrong with it. Remember that spacing is important in stylus.

Comment: Maybe it is not possible to do what I want but you don't understand me or I have not explained well. I want a user to enter the values of a grid and that already has a breakpoint of 500 pixels, that works well in my code. The problem is if the user also want to add another different breakpoint  because it is added to that already exists and overwrites the user defined.

In your example the user must define the breakpoint of 500 pixels and I do not want that.

Comment: Yeah you're correct. I don't understand what you want. Sorry and good luck with finding an answer. Hopefully someone can help you!

Comment: Thank you very much for spending so much time trying to help me ;)

Comment: No problem at all. Hopefully my answer could be useful to someone else in the future :)